elixir/erlang stacktrace. Correct function call interpretation
How to interpret a function attribute in FunctionClauseError
 %FunctionClauseError{
   module: MyApp.MyModule,
   function: :"-load_data/4-inlined-0-",
   arity: 1,
   kind: nil,
   args: nil,
   clauses: nil
}

The term -load_data/4-inlined-0- points to something inside the load_data/4 function.
How to interpret this part: inlined-0?
This part of the environment seems to be undocumented. Can anyone elaborate on this subject?

That doesn't look right... when you define a function with def, its name is limited to certain characters.  Although the function name :"-load_data/4-inlined-0-" is an atom, that's not something you could define with def.  My guess is that you're trying to call a variable-named function using apply/3 (e.g. apply(MyModule, :some_fun, [arg1, arg2])), but you're using an invalid function name somehow.

Obviously i have got definition for load_data/4 function, and this error points to that definition. The value -load_data/4-inlined-0- looks odd i agree, but this is how elixir informs you that something went wrong inside your function body. Another example i know is FunctionClauseError in anonymous function call defined inside named function, which can be represented by function: :\"-load_data/4-func-0-\"
Note that the value of the function attribute inside FunctionClauseError is always type of atom, so it is valid function name.

... or it is better to say it could be valid function name, but it really isn't a function name, not as a whole.

The -load_data/4-inlined-0- function name occurs when an anonymous function is inlined by the compiler, and the call to the anonymous function fails with a function clause error. It is not the name of an actual function; it was added to fix this issue, titled "Confusing case_clause exception instead of function_clause".  I don't think this is documented anywhere.

This requires a little history lesson.  Let's consider this piece of code:
-module(foo).

-export([foo/0]).

foo() ->
    F = fun(X) when is_atom(X) -> ok end,
    F(0).

That is, we create an anonymous function, and then we call it in a way that causes a function clause error.
Inlining of anonymous functions was introduced in Erlang/OTP 24.  Thus, when running this in Erlang 23, we can see that the function name in the stack trace is the usual name for anonymous functions, with -fun-:
> catch foo:foo().
{'EXIT',{function_clause,[{foo,'-foo/0-fun-0-',
                               [0],
                               [{file,"foo.erl"},{line,6}]},
                          {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,684}]},
                          {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,437}]},
                          {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,686}]},
                          {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,642}]},
                          {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,627}]}]}}

In Erlang 24, the function is inlined by the compiler, and gets rewritten to a case expression.  Therefore, we see a case_clause exception, and the stack trace suggests that the error occurred in the foo function itself:
> catch foo:foo().
{'EXIT',{{case_clause,{0}},
         [{foo,foo,0,[{file,"foo.erl"},{line,6}]},
          {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,689}]},
          {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,434}]},
          {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,686}]},
          {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,642}]},
          {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,627}]}]}}

Of course, that's confusing for a programmer who goes looking for a case expression to find the cause of the error, and doesn't find any.  That's why Erlang 25 makes sure to use an actual function_clause exception, to reflect the fact that the error occurred at a place where there was a function call in the code.  It uses -inlined- instead of -fun- since the anonymous function is no longer present in the compiled module:
> catch foo:foo().
{'EXIT',{function_clause,[{foo,'-foo/0-inlined-0-',
                               [0],
                               [{file,"foo.erl"},{line,6}]},
                          {erl_eval,do_apply,7,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,748}]},
                          {erl_eval,expr,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,480}]},
                          {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,691}]},
                          {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,647}]},
                          {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,632}]}]}}

